# Very Messy Integral.

Tags: integration

Find:
$$\large \left|\int_{-\frac1{\sqrt3}}^{\frac1{\sqrt3}}\frac{\ln|x|^x+(\arcsin x)^3(\arctan x)-(1+x^2)\arctan x}{(\ln|x|)^2(x+x^3)}dx\right|$$ 
I got this question recently in an exam, I solved it but it was very innovative so I wanted to share with you all, the answer is hinted as,I would suggest trying it first on your own:

**Spoiler:**

> The second term is odd, which becomes zero, the first term expanded by integration by parts cancel the third and we easily get it's value.

Comment: @DavidMitra see now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the parity and simplify to obtain

$$\int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{\ln \lvert x\rvert^x +(\arcsin x)^3(\arctan x) - (1+x^2)\arctan x}{(\ln \lvert x\rvert)^2(x+x^3)}\,dx = \int_{-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}}^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}} \frac{1}{(\ln \lvert x\rvert)(1+x^2)} - \frac{\arctan x}{x(\ln\lvert x\rvert)^2}\,dx.$$

You may recognise the integrand now as the derivative of

$$\frac{\arctan x}{\ln \lvert x\rvert}$$

(with a small problem at $0$, but that's not a deal-breaker).